# Where can I get a list of all College/University e-mail domains?

Tags: email-validation

I am trying to build an application that is exclusive to college students and need to validate their e-mail address with a list of all valid university/college e-mail domains.

Does anyone know where there is a list of some sort that has all these e-mail domains listed?
(i.e. someEmail@ucberkeley.edu)

*UPDATE*
Ok so to be more specific, I need to actually match email domains uniquely.
i.e. If John Smith has a @ucla.edu, he should only be able to see other users with @ucla.edu e-mails.

That is why I am not just validating a '.edu' email, but instead need a list of valid '.edu' email domains.
Also, I can't just use the school's domain. I know some schools use different email domains (for instance, Sonoma.edu actually uses '@seawolf.sonoma.edu' through a gmail account for their student emails)
Hope that clarifies!

Comment: I'd suggest you start with the .edu registry, and maybe work from there.  My understanding is that .edu is reasonably clean.  A lot of non-US institutions go by their country codes though, and I'd tend to doubt that they're exhaustively archived anywhere.

Comment: Anything wrong with just using .edu? http://net.educause.edu/edudomain/eligibility.asp

Comment: http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/ might also help, though, again, it's US-only.  One question you need to ask, though, is how fiercely you want to police this.  People can spoof domains without *all* that much trouble, after all.  Are you intending to go to the effort of defending against *that*?

Comment: Have you seen [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/mail/college-email/part1/) ? Can you be more specific regarding your requirements ? I.e Any tertiary institution in any country ? Or something more refined ? How do you stop alumni, tertiary staff and other people with a tertiary institution  email cloak bypassing your restriction ?

Comment: See above update for clarification

Comment: Alright here is a little suggestion for you issue. Compile a list of every college in the U.S., after some digging, they can be found on college app sites (not sure if it is possible to copyright a list). Get the list into a db. When the user signs up with their email, search the college list db with the email domain. Suggest their potential college based upon the result, and if it is incorrect, they can change it.

Comment: This is not off-topic...

Answer (score 20):

This list is quite massive - perhaps useful:
https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a site that only allows .edu domains. I need the names of the schools for displaying to the users, so I can't use a solution like the one provided by @JonBiere. As such, I compiled a list. I started with the link provided by @DavidAdams and found other domains here and there. I would have included the list in this answer, but the body is limited to 30,000 characters, so I put it [here](http://pastebin.com/LND21t5F). Feel free to do whatever you want with it.

My plan is to make it so that whenever a user registers and confirms their email address, I'll check my database to see if the newly registered user's email domain is already in the database. If it's not, I'll add it to the database. I'll just have the name of the school be the same as the domain (so it will be domain: example.edu, name: example.edu). Then I'll have a cron job that checks for any of these entries in the database where the domain and name match. If any are found, I'll get an email instructing me to update the "name" field with a proper value (e.g. "Example University"). With this strategy, most popular schools *should* already have an entry to begin with and the more obscure ones will get an entry as users register and confirm their email address.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked awhile ago but I was recently struggling with the same problem with a web application I am building. Rather than validating a user by the specific school domain just use what other people are suggesting and only allow .edu domains. I am assuming you are storing registered users in a database somewhere? If so you should be able to achieve what you want with some simple application logic. I am using Entity Framework so a query would look something like this:

```
var userObj = Context.Users.Where(u => u.user == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).FirstorDefault();

string email = userObj.email;
string[] words = email.Split('@');

var classmates = Context.Users.Where(u => u.email.EndsWith(words[1])).ToList();
```

The classmates variable will now have all the users with the same school email address.

Hope this helps at least someone!

Comment: .edu domains are only widespread in the US and not in other countries like Germany!

Answer (score 0):

I found this list. It's old, but since there's not a lot of churn in Universities, still mostly up-to-date: http://doors.stanford.edu/universities.html
If you end up building an updated list based on this, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: This list only contains 1088 universities. @jllassen answer is much better (9727 domains at the moments).